# Paroli relative al as-tempo "ĝenerala"

Tags: verbs, subordinate-clauses

La as-tempo povas esti uzata por tempo aŭ reala (t.e. okazanta nun) aŭ ĝenerala (ekz por priskribi kutimon/kiamon/ktp). Kiam io okazas relative al io en kiam-frazo, ĉu estas [pli] ĝuste reprezenti la tempon per denove as-tempo ĝenerala aŭ per anstatŭe tempo logika? Jen estas ekzemplo por klarigi.

> Kiam [ajn] mia monado dorlotbesta kuketon ŝtelas, mi ĝin pun{a,o}s.

La as-tempo uzatas ĉar la ŝtelado estas kutima/ofta/ktp. Ĉu la tempo de la dua frazo do devus esti prezenca (kongrue kun tiu de la unua tiel, kiel rilatus du frazoj en us-modo) aŭ futura (t.e. rilato logika)?

Answer (score 2):

Oni uzas la as-tempon por montri kutiman agon aŭ staton sendepende de tempo. Do kvankam punado okazas post ŝteladon, oni malgraŭe diru "punas".

[PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/reala/nun-tempo.html) konstatas pri la as-finaĵo (mia emfazo):

> AS-verbo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato estas reala, efektiva, kaj ke ĝi komenciĝis, sed ne finiĝis. Tio signifas, ke la ago aŭ stato okazas ĝuste nun, aŭ ke ĝi okazas kutime, aŭ ke la **afero validas ĉiam**.

Comment: Ĉu estas same/simile en la okazo de "se" (anstataŭ "kiam"), de "ĝis" (ekz "punas ĝis ĝi ĉesas"), ktp?

Comment: Miakomprene jes. Vi eble volas legi pri uzo de "kiam" kiel kondiĉo en [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/tabelvortoj_am.html#i-kub).